# Sketch/Figma: Using JSON as a color/typography library

Tags: sketch-app, figma

I have JSON with typography/color data. Is there any way to use this data in a Figma or Sketch so that I could've corrected it and then override it?

Answer (score 1):

You're looking for **design token** management.

For figma there are several plugins that allow you to manage the json and import:
https://www.figma.com/community/search?resource_type=plugins&sort_by=relevancy&query=tokens&editor_type=all&price=all&creators=all

For Sketch I know they offer native color token management, but I'm unsure if there's any way of getting typography tokens in/out:
https://www.sketch.com/blog/color-tokens/

Answer (score 0):

Check out the Figma plugin Generate Palette

https://www.figma.com/community/plugin/781017118947202678/Generate-Palette